# What is libmuxer library ? If I run my server or application then I find these

Tags: java, weblogic

If I run my program or server then I find alsways this error message. Can anyone tell me and help me please.. I will be very thankfull to you.

```
<Jul 29, 2013 3:01:55 AM ACT> <Error> <Socket> <BEA-000433> <Unable to load performance     pack. Using Java I/O instead. 
Please ensure that libmuxer library is in :'C:\j2sdk1.4.2_17\bin;C:\bea\weblogic81\bin;C:\bea\weblogic81\server\bin'
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no muxer in java.library.path
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no muxer in java.library.path
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1517)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:788)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:834)
at weblogic.socket.PosixSocketMuxer.<init>(PosixSocketMuxer.java:30)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:274)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:308)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:261)
at weblogic.socket.SocketMuxer.makeTheMuxer(SocketMuxer.java:82)
at weblogic.socket.SocketMuxer.getMuxer(SocketMuxer.java:49)
at weblogic.t3.srvr.ListenThread.initServerSocket(ListenThread.java:690)
at weblogic.t3.srvr.ListenThread.run(ListenThread.java:205)
```

Answer (score 4):

"...this indicates that the Native Libraries are not properly being picked up the Weblogic server. This happens when the weblogic installed as 32 Bit on a 64 Bit Operating System or vice versa. In such scenario we need to explicitly specify the path to the Native Library."

1. Add the following to the setDomainEnv.sh 
    -Djava.library.path=/opt/bea/wlserver_10.3/server/native/solaris/sparc64/
2. Enable  "Native IO" check box under each servers Tuning Tab.
3. Restart the servers.

http://weblogic.middlewarebase.com/2013/04/unable-to-load-performance-pack-using.html

Comment: but dude i am using weblogic 8.1 and this solution is for 10.3.. 
please tell me about 8.1 i will be very thankful to you

Answer (score 0):

I have the some problem, and thanks to [sᴜʀᴇsʜ-ᴀᴛᴛᴀ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1927832/s%E1%B4%9C%CA%80%E1%B4%87s%CA%9C-%E1%B4%80%E1%B4%9B%E1%B4%9B%E1%B4%80) for the hint! It looks like a 32bit/64bit issue. By the way, I'm using WebLogic 12 on a 64bit Centos5.

Note that the libmuxer.so is provided with weblogic for many archs, in fact

```
$ find $MW_HOME -name *muxer*
/application/weblogic/wlserver/server/native/macosx/libmuxer.jnilib
/application/weblogic/wlserver/server/native/linux/s390/libmuxer.so
/application/weblogic/wlserver/server/native/linux/ia64/libmuxer.so
/application/weblogic/wlserver/server/native/linux/x86_64/libmuxer.so
/application/weblogic/wlserver/server/native/linux/i686/libmuxer.so  
/application/weblogic/wlserver/server/native/linux/s390x/libmuxer.so
```

I edited the file *$MW_HOME/wlserver/common/bin/commEnv.sh*, where I found

```
#JAVA_USE_64BIT, true if JVM uses 64 bit operations
JAVA_USE_64BIT=false
```

and updated with

```
#JAVA_USE_64BIT, true if JVM uses 64 bit operations
JAVA_USE_64BIT=true
```

This worked for me, the Error you reported is gone.

Good luck!